How to sync VSCode extensions between local editor and Github Codespaces?
I'm using Github codespaces more and more, and having my extensions preloaded upon setting up a new codespace would speed up my development process a lot.
What should I do so I never have to go back to this again?
I have tried to modify the settings.json to include the extensions in this format
  "github.codespaces.defaultExtensions": [
    "extension.1",
    "extension.2",
    "extension.3",
    "extension...",
  ]


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You may have to login to your VSCode local, setting up everything including GitHub Copilot extension. Subsequently enable Sync Settings to your account, it will come to sync on your codespaces, you don't need to add it manually
https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-your-user-preferences/personalizing-github-codespaces-for-your-account#settings-sync

For example, a common use of Settings Sync would be to sync your settings from your VS Code desktop application, which you use for local work, to codespaces you open in the browser. To do this, you would need to do the following things.

Turn on Settings Sync in the desktop application. For more information, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_turning-on-settings-sync in the VS Code documentation.
Enable Settings Sync in your user preferences for GitHub Codespaces. For more information, see "https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-your-user-preferences/personalizing-github-codespaces-for-your-account#managing-your-preferences-for-settings-sync."

